# Como fazer correlação entre variáveis qualitativas e quantitativas no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um quadro de dados em que tenho variáveis qualitativas, tipo sexo e origem, e variáveis quantitativas como taxa de colesterol, peso e altura. É possível correlacionar essas variáveis usando a função `cor()`, ao utiliza-la recebo um aviso que a variável deve ser apenas numérica:

```
cor(rehab.2)
```

> Error in cor(rehab.2) : 'x' deve ser numérico

Existe alguma função que consegue correlacionar todas essas variáveis no R, independentemente se for quantitativa ou qualitativa?

Exemplo do meu quadro de dados:

[image]

Comment: Isto não é uma questão do R, e sim uma questão matemática/estatística. A correlação é uma conta matemática que precisa de valores numéricos de duas variáveis, não tem como ser feita com uma variável categórica. Você pode explorar outras formas de analisar os dados, mas acho que apenas de estatística descritiva.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como já disseram, essa é uma pergunta mais relacionada a estatística, mas como não tem um statexchange em português eu vou te ajudar nessa.

O método de correlação que você está tentando só vai funcionar para variáveis numéricas, se você quer criar visualizar relações entre variáveis categóricas com variáveis continuas o que eu recomendo mais seria boxplots ou histogramas/densidade.

Vou demonstrar alguns exemplos em R dessas análises. Para isso estou utilizando o dataset `iris`que se encontra no pacote padrão do R `datasets` e o pacote `ggplot2` para plotar os gráficos. Dentro do dataset vamos comparar as os diferentes tamanhos das sépalas `iris$Sepal.Length` das diferentes espécies que temos `iris$Species`.

#### BOXPLOT

```
require(datasets)
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: Boxplot]

#### DENSIDADE

```
require(datasets)
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.3)
```

[image: Densidade]

Mas caso você realmente queira um "número" para se guiar, um teste ANOVA pode te dar isso, basicamente ele vai te dizer se as diferenças das médias (o teste pode ser aplicado a outros atributos) da sua variável continua para cada categoria são "estatisticamente significantes".

#### ANOVA

```
require(datasets)

anova <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
summary(anova)
```

output:

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Species       2  63.21  31.606   119.3 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   147  38.96   0.265                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Nesse caso a hipótese nula de que as Sépalas possuem uma média de tamanho igual é rejeitada por um p-valor <2e-16 (basicamente zero), de forma que pode-se dizer que a espécie é um fator relevante, "correlacionado" ao tamanho da sépala dessas plantas.

obs: provavelmente falei algumas besteiras ai, mas espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de obter um coeficiente que mede a intensidade da associação entre uma variável categórica e uma variável contínua é usar a **raiz quadrada do coeficiente de determinação de um modelo de regressão logística ajustado**.

Essa ideia veio de uma [pergunta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129587/44359) que eu fiz no [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129587/44359) algum tempo atrás.

A raíz quadrada do coeficiente de determinação é sempre um número entre 0 e 1. 1 indicando muito relacionado e 0 pouco relacionado, assim como o coeficiente de correlação de Pearson. O uso desta medida parece fazer sentido uma vez que na regressão linear simples o `R^2` é equivalente ao quadrado da correlação de Pearson.

No `R`, isso uma função pode ser facilmente escrita da seguinte forma:

```
cor_cat_cont <- function(cat, cont){
  modelo <- glm(cat ~ cont, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                control = glm.control(maxit = 10e6))

  R2 <- binomTools::Rsq(modelo)$R2cor
  sqrt(R2)  
}
```

Por exemplo, no banco de dados `iris`, você pode usá-la assim:

```
> cor_cat_cont(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length)
[1] 0.8158366
```

Para usar a função, você precisa instalar o pacote `binomTools`, usando `install.packages("binomTools")`.

Na época fiz o seguinte [post no meu blog](http://dfalbel.github.io/2014/12/coeficiente-correlacao-continua-categorica.html) simulando alguns dados categóricos e medindo a correlação calculada desta forma e achei o resultado bem satisfatório.